# Regarding action of a group factoring through

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, group-actions

Suppose I have a group $G$ which acts on a set $X$. Suppose I can find $H$ a subgroup of $G$ which acts trivially on $X$. 
Does it then automatically mean that the action factors through?

I can see it is we can show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$... If $H$ acts trivially on $X$ then is it always a normal subgroup of $G$? Thank you.

Comment: No this does not imply that $H$is a normal subgroup of $G$. For example $G$ could act trivially on $X$ in which case $H$ could be an arbitrary subgroup.

Comment: However, $H$ is a subgroup of the kernel $K$ of $G\longrightarrow \mathfrak S_X$, so the action of $G$ factors through $G/K$, but that's no real news.